# Assign param in function postgres

Tags: postgresql, function, set, locale

I have this function is postgres 9.5:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION report_summary(lang TEXT)
...
BEGIN
SET LC_TIME = lang
...
```

I want assign language in function to LC_TIME. lang is 'es_ES.UTF-8', etc. But not work. Also, I want if lang not exist, assign default:

Ex:

```
SET LC_TIME = lang or DEFAUT;
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use a dynamic query:

```
EXECUTE 'SET lc_time = ' || quote_ident(lang);
```

Or better yet, change the setting with `set_config`:

```
PERFORM set_config('lc_time', lang, FALSE);
```